# Convert array keys to formatted class names

Tags: php, arrays, replace, concatenation

I need to take this array and convert only the **keys** into one string. Looking for an efficient way to do this.

1. Each element having a period added before the name **( .first_post )**
2. Concatenated with another string and space before each class name
       **( .navigation .first_post )**
3. A comma after the name **( .navigation
       .first_post, )**
4. Replace the **"_"** to **"-"** **( .navigation .first-post, )**

Items

```
array (
  'first_post' => 'First Post' 
  'first_page' => 'First Page' 
  'prev_page' => 'Previous Page'
  'next_page' => 'Next Page'
  'last_page' => 'Last Page'
  'last_post' => 'Last Post'
);
```

This is what I am hoping for

```
.navigation .first-post, .navigation .first-page, .navigation .prev-post,
.navigation .next-page, .navigation .last-page, .navigation .last-post
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) gives you an elegant way of applying a transformation to each of an array's elements. After doing that, all you need to do is [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) the result to concatenate all the values:

```
$arr = array (
  'first_post' => 'First Post',
  'first_page' => 'First Page',
  'prev_page' => 'Previous Page',
  'next_page' => 'Next Page',
  'last_page' => 'Last Page',
  'last_post' => 'Last Post'
);

function transform($x) {
    return '.navigation .' . str_replace('_', '-', $x);
};

$result = implode(', ', array_map('transform', array_keys($arr)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace/add key with new values

```
foreach($arr as $k=>$v){
    $k = '.navigation .'.str_replace('_', '-', $k);
    $newarr[$k] = $v;
}
print_r($newarr);
```

if you want keys as comma separated string

```
$str = implode(", ", array_keys($newarr))
```